# Preventing google maps Markers to "fly" up when dragged

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps Flash API and I have a bullseye Marker that the user should drag to the correct position, but whenever you drag something it flies up a bit and this stupid target cross appears below, which is what I would like to prevent, because it doesn't look nice and I'd even say it's confusing.

The only idea I have so far is to set an offset to the icon to compensate for the "flying" height whenever the user clicks the marker, but I figured maybe there is a hidden option somewhere to do that, or just one that I didn't get from the documentation, but I think I tried it all by now.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
var square = new GIcon();

square.dragCrossImage = ""; // no image for the cross
square.maxHeight = 0.1; // it only raises a fraction of a bit

square.image = "/edit/images/square.gif";
square.shadow = "";
square.iconSize = new GSize(10, 10);
square.shadowSize = new GSize(5, 5);
square.iconAnchor = new GPoint(5, 5);
square.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(15, 15);
```

passing the optional property **dragCrossMove: false**